# Akka actor not loading custom mailbox configuration properly

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, actor, typesafe-config

I'm trying to define a custom mailbox with guaranteed uniqueness of messages, as well as priority, for an actor in Play 2.5.

I get this exception:

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, akka.ConfigurationException: Type [jobs.SteamInfoUpdater.MyPrioQueueSematics] specified as akka.actor.mailbox.requirement [unique-prio-mailbox] in config can't be loaded due to [jobs.SteamInfoUpdater.MyPrioQueueSematics]
  while locating play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider
  while locating akka.actor.ActorSystem
    for field at play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorRefProvider.actorSystem(Akka.scala:205)
  while locating play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorRefProvider
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport$class.bindActor(Akka.scala:139) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> modules.ServiceModule)
```

I have the following in my config:

```
unique-prio-mailbox{
  mailbox-type = "jobs.SteamInfoUpdater.UniquePriorityMailbox"
}
akka.actor.mailbox.requirements {
  "jobs.SteamInfoUpdater.MyPrioQueueSematics" = unique-prio-mailbox
}
```

I think the problem has to do with the config not being able to load `MyPriorityQueueSemantics`, because if I change the configuration to:

```
akka.actor.mailbox.requirements {
      "test" = unique-prio-mailbox
    }
```

I get this:

```
Error in custom provider, akka.ConfigurationException: Type [test] specified as akka.actor.mailbox.requirement [unique-prio-mailbox] in config can't be loaded due to [test]
```

This is my mailbox implementation:

```
trait MyPrioQueueSematics

  class UniquePriorityMessageQueue extends MessageQueue
    with MyPrioQueueSematics {

    private final val queue = new UniquePriorityBlockingQueue[Envelope](500, Ordering.by(e => e.message match {
      case m: InfoUpdaterMessage => m.priority
      case _ => Int.MaxValue
    }))

    def enqueue(receiver: ActorRef, handle: Envelope): Unit =
      queue.offer(handle)

    def dequeue(): Envelope = queue.poll()

    def numberOfMessages: Int = queue.size

    def hasMessages: Boolean = !queue.isEmpty

    def cleanUp(owner: ActorRef, deadLetters: MessageQueue) {
      while (hasMessages) {
        deadLetters.enqueue(owner, dequeue())
      }
    }
  }

class UniquePriorityBlockingQueue[T](initialCapacity: Int, ordering: Ordering[T]) extends ForwardingQueue[T] {
    override def delegate(): util.Queue[T] = new PriorityBlockingQueue[T](initialCapacity, ordering)

    override def add(element: T): Boolean = if (super.contains(element)) {
      false
    } else {
      super.add(element)
    }

    override def offer(o: T): Boolean = standardOffer(o)
  }

  class UniquePriorityMailbox extends MailboxType with ProducesMessageQueue[UniquePriorityMessageQueue] {

    def this(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, config: Config) = {
      this()
    }

    final override def create(
      owner: Option[ActorRef],
      system: Option[ActorSystem]): MessageQueue =
      new UniquePriorityMessageQueue()
  }
```

I've followed this guide: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/mailboxes.html

Comment: Are you sure jobs.SteamInfoUpdater.MyPrioQueueSematics is the correct FQCN?

Comment: I was pretty sure. I now realise semantics was misspelt, but that was the case in the source as well. I'd tried just `SteamInfoUpdater.MyPrioQueueSemantics`, and also just `jobs.MyPrioQueueSemantics`, with the same results. I then tried moving the `MyPrioQueueSemantics` trait out of the SteamInfoUpdater companion object, restulting in a `ClassNotFoundException` on `UniquePriorityMailbox`. Progress! I then moved all of the mailbox related classes out of the companion object, and it worked! My guess is the reflection didn't like the nested classes and expected the whole path to be package names.